# printing a random string from an array list with no duplicates

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

Basically, I have an array and I want it to be transferred to a label when a button is pressed. The main issue I am having is I can't figure out a way to have the array not duplicate something once it has already been printed

here is a snippet of my code

```
 @IBOutlet weak var truthspot: UILabel!

@IBAction func truthclick(_ sender: Any) {

    let array = ["pasta", "boop", "test1", "test2"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))

    truthspot.text = (array[randomIndex])
```

Comment: What about removing the item in `array` once it's printed?

Comment: super swift noob here, do you mean just printing "randomIndex"?

Comment: `array.remove(at: randomIndex)` just after `truthspot.text =`. This way it won't appear anymore in the array and in the next random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move `array` outside your function and remove the element at the generated index each time the function was called.

```
var array = ["pasta", "boop", "test1", "test2"]

@IBAction func truthclick(_ sender: Any) {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))

    truthspot.text = (array[randomIndex])

    array.remove(at: randomIndex)
}
```

Comment: You may want to remove AFTER `truthspot.text =`, else if randomIndex is the index of the last object, you'll get a crash (out of bound), and in other cases, you'll get the wrong value.

Comment: thank you so much this is perfect!

is there any way that i could add a restart loop to the end so the application doesn't crash?

Comment: You can use a second array for that purpose where you can repopulate the first array from. Check if `count` is 0 for your first array and make your second array equal to the first one if that is the case.

Comment: @the4kman would you be able to show me a demo of how that would look like